# invalid project description (in eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new in eclipse, i am trying to open existing project and i did search a lot but i dont know what i am doing wrong. Coming from C++ visual studio finding great difficulty in opening the existing project.

here is how i am opening:
              file->import->Anriod->Existing Android Code in workspace -> ...root directory

I think illustrating through pic makes easier to understand that what i am doing wrong, here is my screen shots which would help to understand my problem:

at start of eclipse:

[image]

current file place in driver/folder :

[image]

the samplewideget folder internal:

[image]

when i select root directory it gives me error:

[image]

DO i have to select also inside folder somthing also??
soory for bad english:

Comment: This may mean there is something wrong in the `.project` file. Can you show us the contents of that.

Comment: may be your take a project and import the project in same locations,so  your possible to get this error

Comment: content means all files and folders? 2nd pic is the name of the folder that i want to open its files and all resources and data.

Answer (score 0):

First Check your Workspece and delete Project you import if available.and
you could do is try creating a project of a different name (from the first project's source), so that the workspace will contain the new project as a functional project. Then, go into your workspace directory and absolutely delete the folder that contained the original project, or move it. Try loading the project from source again, this time using the second project, by naming it with the correct name. Or, you could try refactoring the second project back to the first's name.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the project folder one directory lower . Make another folder in your root directory & copy your project into that folder . Now import the project with this newly created folder.